# How to split a branch in two with Git?

Tags: git, split, branch, rebase, cut

I've made a `feature` branch from `master` and then realize at some point that it will be better to start a new branch from this branch.

So, how to split a branch in two at a specific commit ?

Let me explain with this little schema:

I have this:

```
master ───●──●──●──●──●──●──●──●──●──●
              \                    
               \                   
        feature ●──●──●──●──●──●──●
                         ▲         
                         │         
                    split here
```

and i wish this:

```
master ───●──●──●──●──●──●──●──●──●──●   
              \                       
               \                      
        feature ●──●──●──●            
                          \           
                           \          
              feature-test  ●──●──●
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first step is to create `feature_test` where `feature` is:

```
git checkout feature
git checkout -b feature-test
```

But you *also* need to reset `feature` to `<sha1 split here>`:

```
git checkout feature
git reset --hard <sha1 split here>
```

Note that if you already pushed `feature`, you will need to do a `git push --force`.
And that might prove inconvenient for other collaborators who might already have pulled from `origin/feature`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `git reset hard` what was missing to undo commits in `feature`. I'm alone on this branch, so nobody unless me has push on `origin/feature`

Comment: Haha :) thanks @VonC ! i'm trying to learn every piece of git and make tutorial of them.

Comment: I think that's not the correct (or complete) answer. After running the first command all commits after the "split" are lost on on the newly created branch. After resetting hard the former branch all commits are lost. That's not that what the author asked for.

Comment: @kalamar OK. I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the exact commit in your `feature` branch whence you want the new `feature-test` branch to begin.  Then create a new branch called `feature-test` from that commit:

```
git checkout <sha1 in feature>
git checkout -b feature-test
```

To obtain the SHA-1 hash for your desired commit in the `feature` branch, you can use `git log` and find the commit you want.  The entry will look something like this:

```
commit 408d94384216f890ff7a0c3528e8bed1e0b01621
Author: Yadomi <yadomi@somewhere.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 11 18:10:52 2015 -0700
```

If you want to accomplish the same thing with just one Git command, you could also try the following:

```
git checkout -b feature-test 408d94384216f890ff7a0c3528e8bed1e0b01621
```

Here, I have used the SHA-1 has from the sample Git log, but you can replace it with whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks ! so now i've my `feature-test` with a good base, but every commit made after 408d943842... (for exemple) isn't there and stay in `feature` branch. How do I move those commits ?

Answer (score 1):

Another option that was not mentioned (now its too late but for next time) don't commit all your changes at once and use hunks.

you can do it by using the `-p` flag in the add command. `git add -p` and then only add what you need, create a second branch and commit the rest.

Just to clarify: git add -p let you choose which changes to add to commit and not to pick up a specific commits.

---

If your need to pick up commits that not in a single range then you can use `git cherry-pick` to pick the specific commits.